# Mobile chat app send button: on keyboard or interface?

Tags: mobile, social-interfaces, chat

You would think that having the button closer to where you're typing would be more ergonomic, but I've been tripped up by the keyboard location on snapchat before. Can the "on-interface" send button used in Messenger be considered a convention now?

Best examples I can think of:

**Messenger - send button beside input**

[image: Messenger]

**Snapchat - send button on keyboard**

[image: Snapchat]

Comment: I think it depends if you are expecting new lines (usually where "send" button is, there is a "return" button to introduce line feeds) in the text or not. In snapchat, you can't have line breaks, but in messenger you can, hence the different placement of the "send" button.

Comment: I would "learn" from the most used apps out there. WhatsApp, iMessage etc'. They figured it out for you. It's not the best answer ( It's scenario-depended). But you may get some good insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer might depend on context or expected behaviour of the field, e.g return for new line, as mentioned by @hd.

I don't think you can call it convention.

I believe that button on interface is usually better since you remove the ambiguity of the bottom right keyboard button sometimes being return, sometimes being send. It's one less thing for user to think.

No one will expect a clear SEND button on the interface to add a new line, but some people might need to think if that "return" button is going to send the message, like it did when they were using Snapchat, or break the line, like when they were sending an email.

When in doubt, I always go with the solution with less potential for errors or misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 2):

The expected behaviour depends on the user itself. Some may expect `new line` to send the message immediately, some would like to use it as line break.

The question is - does the default keyboard on the mobile device allow for a `send` button or you'd need to implement your own keyboard for the app? I would discourage you from the latter as it may create inconsistency, especially for the users with custom keyboard (and the "system-wide" keyboard differs between manufacturers).

In my opinion the convention is still "make it configurable", however the default behaviour depends on the type of the application - an email client would have a separate `send` button, an app for short messages may have it right on the keyboard.